# Find a linearly independent subset and extend it to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Im confused. Aren't these subsets already linearly independent both i), j)? Also they both for a basis for $R^3$ ? Am I missing something

Comment: No the second set is linearily dependent. The sum of the first two is the third.

Comment: I agree with you about the first set. It's already L.I. over $\mathbb{R}$, and it's spanning, so there's no extension required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over $\mathbb R$, yes, but not over $\mathbb F_2$. In this last case, the sum of the three vectors is $(0,0,0)$, and therefore they are linearly *dependent*.

Comment: is 1+1=0 here?.

Comment: Yes, since $\mathbb F_2=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb F_2$ we have $1+1=0$ and hence
$$
(1,1,0)+(1,0,1)=(0,1,1).
$$
So the three vectors are linearly dependent over $\Bbb F_2$.